# Why did friend's likes disappear from my posts on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

One of my friends deactivated his account. So his likes disappeared from my posts but a strange thing happened. One of my other friend's likes also disappeared from my post although his account is not deactivated. And as soon as the first friend reactivated his account then likes of both the friends appeared again. Why did this happen?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks to be troubleshooting like question and this question aren't a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a glitch, you can [report](https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049) about it to Facebook.

Before that, I would suggest just check one more time. Ask your friend to deactivate and reactivate his account and see if it happens again or not.

Comment: I confirmed it sir .. Also report to facebook but no progress there

Comment: Is that posible k these guys linked there accounts somehow

Comment: If you have reported, then wait for reply from Facebook. We can not do anything from their end.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of conjecture, but if your second friend "liked" your posts because they saw them on your first friend's timeline, that might explain why they disappeared when the first friend deactivated their account and re-appeared when it was re-activated. The "like" was "transferred" to your post "through" the first friend.

This makes more sense to me if the likes are from before you and the second friend became Facebook friends, but so much of what Facebook does in inscrutable.